# how to automatically send markdowns into the sale sections?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento-1.8

when I make some markdowns for the sale items they don't go in the right categories.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when I import the markdowns(change or prices of the items) in this instance I am talking about the sale items, they don't go into the sale sections. Is there a way to do that quicker then choosing them one by one?